# Why isn't my javascript loading in my WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin that uses jquery (already loaded in the head). I can't get my plugin's javascript to load:

```
  function add_my_js(){
        echo 'joy joy joy';
        wp_register_script('hdjs',plugins_url('/css/homedepotslider.js', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('hdjs');
    }

add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_my_js');
```

It will run the function (I see the "joy joy joy") but not load the script. Note: the "joy" text was being used to see if the function even runs.

I loaded my plugin css the same way (using _style) and have no issues.

Thanks!

Comment: is the js file supposed to be in the `/css/` directory? I imagine it should look like: `wp_register_script('hdjs',plugins_url('/js/homedepotslider.js', __FILE__));`

Comment: </facepalm> Thanks @Adam can't believe I was looking over that.

Comment: Always be careful when copy and pasting ;)

Comment: just a rookie mistake. I know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong directory; I doubt the `js` file is in the `css` directory.
Always be careful when copy and pasting.

I imagine it should look like:

```
function add_my_js(){
        echo 'joy joy joy';
        wp_register_script('hdjs',plugins_url('/js/homedepotslider.js', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('hdjs');
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts','add_my_js');
```